# Is it possible to have sushi pizza?

Tags: fish, pizza, sushi

I've found very few places that dare to combine those two in one dish. None of them succeeded, in my opinion.

At first I thought it was due to mixing rice and wheat, then thought it was due to the different temperatures. Whatever the reason, I still want to make something that combines both, something that could be considered pizza and that could also be considered sushi. Is it possible?

Comment: I've seen it advertised in brasil but was way too scared to order it

Comment: A few restaurants in Brazil serve a variant that is basically a sushi roll but filled with the stuff you usually have as pizza toppings - cheese, pepperoni, olives, etc. It is surprisingly tasty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Circular bed of sticky sushi rice, topped with a drizzle of spicy mayo as the sauce and chunks of sashimi. cut into pizza slices.

Comment: It doesn't really have any pizza ingredients, does it? It might be worth trying, though, but I wonder if the rice alone can be sticky enough to hold the toppings...

Comment: @Julio: This isn't just a random a recipe, this is what sushi pizza *actually* is.  It's served in many sushi restaurants across North America.

Comment: Do you eat it like a slice of pizza? Knife and fork?  Chopsticks? Seems like the rice would fall apart if the piece was too big.

Comment: The wikipedia article cited below indicated the sushi rice is fried into a patty, so that would hold together better.

Comment: You guys can ding me for this, but I just thought of it when I read the question. I wouldn't want any "real" pizza ingredients with my raw fish. Crust: no. Tomato sauce: no. Cheese: Hells no!

Comment: @awshepard: Michael explained why it holds together; as for eating it, I've only had it once (I haven't ever seen it in Texas, but was up near Montreal recently) and the whole thing was only maybe 12cm across, and it was cut into six "slices", so they were quite possible to pick up with chopsticks, though the shape is a little more awkward to grab than normal sushi or sushi rolls.

Comment: Only in America would you find something like this. I did have Enchilada Dumplings in Shinjuku Okubo Tokyo, so I suppose anything is possible. But why on Earth would you want to ruin perfectly good sushi is beyond me.

Answer (score 4):

I know that at Morimoto's in New York he has a pizza dish that is essentially sushi ingredients on pizza dough. This is quoted from a NY Times article :

> a 'tuna pizza' with raw bluefin tuna,
>   jalapeño, red onion, olives and an
>   anchovy aioli atop a crisp, thin
>   tortilla. I also liked silky slices of
>   "lamb carpaccio," dressed with
>   Japanese green onions, grated ginger
>   and garlic oil.

Answer (score 3):

I frequent the Vancouver sushi scene and can't say I see this very often if ever.  It seems it does exist though, primarily on the east coast.

[Wikipedia even has an article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi_Pizza), which is proof that it does, in fact, exist. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sushi pizza, as linked and described above, is a very common dish in North Americanized sushi restaurants. It seems to be slightly more popular on the East coast, though I have eaten it both in Vancouver and in Victoria.